# Pod::Usage and Getopts::Long

Tags: perl

I'm using Pod::Usage and Getopts::Long together and works fine for printing usage only if you provide -help or if the arguments are not recognized. However, if the script requires some arguments and no arguments are provided, it does not print anything and just returns to the prompt. How can i get it to print usage if no arguments are given? The following is my code:

```
my ($opt_name); my $opt_help = 0;
GetOptions ('n=s' =>    \$opt_name,
            'help|?' => \$opt_help) or pod2usage(2); pod2usage(1) if $opt_help;    
__END__

=head1 SYNOPSIS

script.pl [-o=<name>]

 Options:
   -n              Name
   -help           Prints usage

=cut
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call pod2usage directly. Just check the settings to see if any have been provided:

```
pod2usage() unless $opt_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: Matthew beat me to it.

I have never used Pod::Usage before, but i would assume:

```
my $opt_REQUIRED_name = ""; my $opt_help = 0;
GetOptions ('n=s' =>    \$opt_REQUIRED_name,
            'help|?' => \$opt_help) or pod2usage(2); pod2usage(1) if $opt_help;
                                          pod2usage(1) if (! $opt_REQUIRED_name);
```

Would that not work?